# Using Socker.io, emitting does nothing just after connecting

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, emit

I just started using [socket.io](https://socket.io/) for my Node.js server. My problem is that I cannot emit anything immediately after connecting.

Nothing happens. No errors. But no emitting !

This is server:

```js
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(3000);
const io = socket(server);

io.on("connect", (socket: Socket) => {
  console.log("Client connected...");

  // This does nothing
  socket.emit("Sending immediately", 'sent!');

  setTimeout(() => {
    socket.emit("Sending with delay", 'delayed');
  }, 1000);
}
```

And the client code is this:

(I'm checking the received messages in Firefox Network tab)

```js
export class Server {
  private io: SocketIOClient.Socket;

  constructor() {
    this.io = io('127.0.0.1:3000');
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have a client listening to the server? If yes, can you post that code?

Comment: @AbiSivam I added the client code.

Comment: Did you try listening to the event in the client?  io.on("Sending immediately", ()=>{console.log('received'}). As far as I know server code looks okay

Comment: @AbiSivam, yes, but nothing happens. Nothing is sent by server. Weird...

How can I reproduce this on a sandbox?